# ActiveMQ and Tomcat (6.x): work together?

Tags: tomcat6, activemq-classic

I'm working on my first ActiveMQ deploy (actually the broker is Apollo). I'd like to use pooled connections as eventually we will have lots of producers and consumers, perhaps in the same VM, sending and receiving lots of messages.

But reading http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-jms-efficiently.html it really is not too clear to me what is the best path to efficiency:

1) camel?
2) spring?
3) PooledConnectionFactory? Is this class even compatible with Tomcat, sure likes to throw exceptions.

JCA does not look like an option since Tomcat 6.x is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat does not really care or even know anything about JMS. So, standard approach would do, like you stated.

As far as performance is concerned, Camel and Spring (which Camel JMS is based upon) does not really add anything to performance, rather the [other way around](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html). These frameworks instead add a lot of convenience when it comes to writing complex JMS applications. The `PoolingConnecitonFactory` class (or even the generic spring class [CachingConnectionFactory])[2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html) enable reuse of objects and hence boosts performance when using Spring based JMS frameworks such as Camel.